# Raspberry GSM Model can't work

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to run this code to send a SMS message:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',baudrate=9600, timeout=3)
ser.write("AT\r")
response = ser.readlines(None)
ser.write("AT+CMGF=1\r")
response = ser.readlines(None)
ser.writ('AT+CMGS="+9693550770"\r')
response = ser.readlines(None)
ser.write("F=Hello Raspberry pi")
ser.weite(ch(26))
time.sleep(19)
ser.close()
```

error:

```
%Run sms.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/sms.py", line 4, in: ser.write("AT\r")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 518, in write d = to_bytes(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 63, in to_bytes 
      raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
  TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: 'AT\r'
```

Comment: You need to edit your post to sort out the formatting. Start code lines with 4 spaces. Read the formatting help for more info. Then you need to explain more about what you are doing and what you are connecting to.

Comment: The clue is the message "Unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes". Try using the method encode('ascii', 'ignore') on your string.

Comment: Also, there are **lots** of typos in your code: `ser.writ`, `ser.weite`. At least check for spelling error before you post

Answer (score 0):

The `write()` method expects bytes instead of strings.  Simplest solution is to prefix the string literals with a `b`.

You also must not try to read more than one line in response to each AT command.  The `readlines()` method reads all lines until the sender closes its end of the connection, so your code will just hang there.

```
import time
import serial


def main():
    with serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=9600, timeout=3) as connection:
        connection.write(b'AT\r')
        _response = connection.readline()
        connection.write(b'AT+CMGF=1\r')
        _response = connection.readline()
        connection.write(b'AT+CMGS="+9693550770"\r')
        _response = connection.readline()
        connection.write(b'F=Hello Raspberry pi\x1a')
        time.sleep(19)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Maybe you want to do something with the responses. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You want to send pure characters as bytes to the serial interface, and you want to use ASCII encoding. Literal "AT\r" is an unicode string object that is not accepted by write method. As Paul Johnson says you want to use `someliteral.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` to make it accepted.

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',baudrate=9600, timeout=3)
def send(x):
    global ser
    ser.write(x.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))

send("AT\r")
...
send("AT+CMGF=1\r")
...
```

Comment: I've down voted for using `global` and encoding (with ignoring potential errors) instead of just using `bytes` literals: `ser.write(b'AT\r')`.

Comment: I wanted to make him a simplest solution that he can easily understand and readily put in and solve his problem.

Comment: Me too. What's simpler than just putting a `b` in front of the string literals?

Comment: Maybe you're just too pushy about scoring. Anyway the user has probably solved his problem already.

Comment: What's that's supposed to mean? And the answers are not just for the OP but also for people who have the same or a similar problem.